# Vertical positioning of text in an <input> field

Tags: css, input, vertical-alignment

I've been unable to specify the vertical position of text in an input field using padding or line-height. The following code SHOULD render a text input with text pushed to the bottom:

```
<input style="padding: 50px 0 0 0; height: 0px;" type="text" value="Hello" />
```

What's happening instead is that all text is being centered vertically in an input that is 50px tall.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: Why is your input height set to 0px. What are you trying to do.

Comment: Ok maybe I should have set the height to like 10 or 20px in this example. The point is, I'm trying to align text to the bottom of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it on a standard textbox without oddball trickery (as in, creating a div with a border that looks like a textbox, and the removing the border from the textbox itself and vertically positioning it to the bottom of the div), so you'll have to resort to a textarea element...

```
<textarea style="padding: 50px 0 0 0; resize: none;">Hello</textarea>
```

(Adding `resize: none;` stops the user from changing the size of the textarea)

Comment: I wanted to avoid the "oddball trickery", but I guess what I will do is something like <label>Email:<input type='text'/></label> and put all the styling in the label.